Loss of adjective in verbalisierung

Die möglichen Auswirkungen (1) der neuen Technologien auf die Qualität unserer Nahrungsmittel kennen (2) nur noch die Experten.

Verbalisierung

Satzumformung


Nur noch ____, wie ___
Soltn: 5. Nur noch Experten wissen, wie (sich) die neuen Technologien (sich) auf die Qualität unserer
Nahrungsmittel auswirken.

When I was doing the problem I was stuck on how to convert möglichen into an adverb. In the solution, it is done without even considering it. Is the semantics of möglichen hidden somewhere in the sentence? Else, did we have no chance except to drop conveying it's meaning for purposes of verbailiserung?

You can employ the -weise adverbs for retaining an adjective that way:

Die möglichen Auswirkungen der neuen Technologien auf die Qualität unserer Nahrungsmittel kennen nur noch die Experten.
Nur noch Experten wissen, wie sich die neuen Technologien möglicherweise auf die Qualität unserer Nahrungsmittel auswirken.

For some adjectives/adverbs, there's matching -seits adverbs:

Die anderen Auswirkungen der neuen Technologien auf die Qualität unserer Nahrungsmittel kennen nur noch die Experten.
Nur noch Experten wissen, wie sich die neuen Technologien andererseits auf die Qualität unserer Nahrungsmittel auswirken.

And for adjectives ending in -ig, the corresponding plain adverb is used.

Die heutigen Auswirkungen der neuen Technologien auf die Qualität unserer Nahrungsmittel kennen nur noch die Experten.
Nur noch Experten wissen, wie sich die neuen Technologien heute auf die Qualität unserer Nahrungsmittel auswirken.


so, to be explicit, the converted sentence doesn't have the semantic of möglichen stored in it?

It should. That's the reason why I put in möglicherweise.

Your use of andererseits is wrong. It means "on the other hand". The fitting word would be anderweit/anderweitig; or farther afield, außerdem, darüber hinaus.
